# I am confused with my Python. ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python

Kida lost here. I am trying to get a consolidated csv and I keep getting this error:

> File "consolidate.py", line 26, in csv_merge.write(line)
>
> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

I tried moving indentation:

```
csv_header='name,location,age,phonenumber'
csv_out = 'consolidated.csv'

csv_d
dir_tree = os.walk(csv_dir)
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in dir_tree:
   pass

csv_list = []
for file in filenames:
   if file.endswith('.csv'):
      csv_list.append(file)

csv_merge = open(csv_out, 'w')
csv_merge.write(csv_header)
csv_merge.write('\n')ir = os.getcwd()
for file in csv_list:
        csv_in = open(file)
        for line in csv_in:
           if line.startswith(csv_header):
              continue
           csv_merge.write(line)
        csv_in.close()
        csv_merge.close()
print('Verify consolidated CSV file : ' + csv_out)
```

But this didn't work. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: You never `open()` csv_merge

Comment: `csv_merge != csv_in`

Comment: How was `csv_merge` initialized?

Comment: Even if you did open `csv_merge`, you close it each time through the loop.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You never open csv_merge properly and even if you do you still close csv_merge after the first item in csv_list is written.

Why are you even using things like `csv_merge.close()`?
The convention is to use things like `with open(csv_merge, 'w') as f:`, that way the file always gets closed, even if the loop or script fails to execute properly.